# VBA pasting data in large chunks

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that finds data in a cell in sheet 1 and pastes it many times, one cell at a time, into cells in another sheet. Which works, expect it takes quite a long time and often freezes the computer. Surely, there is a way to paste that data into all of the designated cells at once, or at least some other way of optimizing it? Any help is appreciated.

```
Dim sourcerange4 As Integer
Dim offset4 As Integer
Dim qproc As Integer
qproc = 1
sourcerange4 = 1
offset4 = 3

     SourceRange3 = 1
      Offset3 = 3
   Do Until qproc = SourceRange * QuestRange
   qproc = qproc + 1

            Sheets(SourceSheet).Select
                    Cells(SourceRange3, Offset3).Copy


            Sheets(RawData).Select
                            Do Until Cells(sourcerange4, offset4) = ""
                                  sourcerange4 = sourcerange4 + 1
                           Loop

            Sheets(RawData).Select
            Cells(sourcerange4, offset4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

    Loop
```

Comment: If your code works as intended, but is just slow or inefficient, I suggest you take the whole procedure (i.e. the full context) to [codereview.se], where you'll receive feedback on any/all aspects of your code, including performance issues.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. How does your outer Do loop ever exit, since SourceRange and QuestRange are neither defined, nor acted upon anywhere? There are multiple .Select statements that don't appear to do anything, and neither of your sheet name variable appear to be defined anywhere. Does this code actually work?

Comment: Something like `Target.Value = Source.Value` transfers values from range `Source` to range `Target` all at once, with no need for selecting, copying and pasting (which are almost always a bad idea in Excel VBA). Determine the sources and the targets (preferably in a way that is more efficient than cell-by-cell looping) and transfer data in large chunks. Also -- don't use `Integer`. It is asking for trouble in modern versions of Excel since valid row indices can overflow that data type. Use `Long` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe in your text, it can be done with the `Resize` method, since you seem to be looping down rows to paste the value.

I used you're references as much as possible and tried to incorporate with your code as is, but it was a bit confusing, so you may need to make some adjustments, but conceptually it should be all there.

```
Dim sCopyValue as String
sCopyValue = Sheets(SourceSheet).Cells(SourceRange3, Offset3).Value

Dim iCopyRows as Integer
iCopyRows = SourceRange * QuestRange
Sheets(RawData).Cells(sourcerange4,offset4).Resize(iCopyRows,1).Value = sCopyValue
```